# Sort favorite questions

Tags: discussion

Is there a way to sort my favorite questions by tag(or time added etc.) in Mathematica, and maybe provide clickable links? I found it difficult to look for a specific favorite question as my favorite list gets longer and longer.
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [the api](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/favorites-on-users), here's a basic example that reads your favorites and then lets you click a tag to display corresponding favorites:

```
res = Import["http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/users/1364/favorites?order=desc&sort=activity&site=mathematica&pagesize=100", "JSON"];
"has_more" /. res
items = ("items" /. res);
withTags[items_, tags_List] := Select[items, Intersection["tags" /. #, tags] == tags &]
itemToLink[item_] := Hyperlink[Column[{"tags", "title"}], "link"] /. item;
Button[First@#,
   output = Column[itemToLink /@ withTags[items, {First@#}]]
   , Appearance -> None] & /@ 
 Sort[Tally[Flatten["tags" /. items]], Last@#1 > Last@#2 &]
Dynamic[output]
```

Answer (score 6):

It is often helpful to search the [main StackExchange Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) when trying to answer questions such as this.  That would lead you to: [Search in list of favorited questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3683) and a query such as:

```
infavorites:mine [programming]
```